# Copying database files when moving application to another computer in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, mysql, database, build, installshield

I currently finished writing my application and I wanted to run the application on a different computer. I built the application using InstallShield project. And when I installed the application and I ran it I got a message telling me that it couldn't connect to the database. So the question is, how to copy the database files while building the application so that it would work on another computer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add required Prerequisites during publish/setup of your application.
App.config file--> change name and add same code in your connection code as shown below:

[image]

[Read More...](http://www.msdotnet.co.in/2013/07/how-to-create-setup-fileexe-with.html#.V2kFQbh96Uk)

Comment: hello, thank you for the answer. I tried changing it but I got so many errors. do you have any idea why?

Comment: `Data Source=.;port=3306;Initial Catalog=your DB name;User Id=root;password=0159` you may have this type of connection string if don't add this in `app.config` and `ProviderName="System.Data.MySqlClient"`

Comment: I found the connection sources from properties. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your database in other Computer and change the connection string from app.config file.

Comment: Do you have any idea where can I find the new connection string? I'm using MySQL by the way.

Comment: put your connection string in app.config file [Source](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/416198/How-to-get-Connection-String-from-App-Config-in-Cs)   and  after installation find [YourAppNAME.exe] file in directory where you installed your app..  open in notepad and update your connection string.